# Is param['pagetoken'] a syntax error in sample Google Reports Code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-reporting-api

I've been trying to decipher the following block of code from the [Google Reports API sample](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/quickstart/quickstart-python)

It appears as though the term `param['pagetoken']` should be `params['pagetoken']`

Am I misreading this?

```
all_logins = []
page_token = None
params = {'applicationName': 'login', 'userKey': 'all', 'startTime': start_time}

while True:
  try:
    if page_token:
      param['pageToken'] = page_token
    current_page = reports_service.activities().list(**params).execute()

  all_logins.extend(current_page['items'])
  page_token = current_page.get('nextPageToken')
  if not page_token:
    break
except errors.HttpError as error:
  print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
  break
```

Comment: Nope, you're not. It's a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell on the report page, that `param[...]` is a typo.  `param` is not referred to anywhere else in the post, however `params` is.